# Cannot map custom http header on response using int-http:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have an int-http:outbound-gateway to a rest service with a custom http header but this header is not mapped to the SI message headers although is set on the mapped-response-headers config

here's my config:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway 
    request-channel="inChannel" reply-channel="outChannel"
    url-expression="http://localhost:8080/rest" mapped-request-headers="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    http-method-expression="GET" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    charset="UTF-8" 
    mapped-response-headers="HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS,mySpecificHeader"/>
```

Here's the raw response from the rest service:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:05:34 GMT
mySpecificHeader: headerInfo
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:05:34 GMT

{"surname":"Constantine","phone":"+33 555 666 777","name":"John","id":12345}
```

Comment: Please, share DEBUG logs for the `org.springframework.integration` category around those `in` and `out` channels for proving the problem.

Comment: Hi! the header was mapped to the SI message header. Sorry for the trouble and thank you very much for your time